# Different types of branches

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu, processor

So my undertanding of branching is there is two types:

two way branch, a branch is taken based on the result of an some computation that is stored in a register. expensive and causes pipeline flushes.

one way branch, this is like a function pointer or a goto, it will go to constant address.  Correct me if im mistaken but I think this are much cheaper than the two branch because modern processors will resolve these instructions early in the pipeline.

I imagined loop unrolling would be faster if a third type of branch existed. Normally, loop unrolling increases instruction size, but avoids the two way branching. What if you had a branch that aovids both instruction size and two branching. Like a branch that does something like loop over a piece of code a constant amount of times.

What type of branchs exist?

Comment: `One way branch` is insufficiently precise: You can have *direct* **unconditional** jumps/calls, or *indirect* unconditional jumps/calls. Direct unconditional jumps/calls are fairly cheap. Indirect unconditional jumps/calls (like function pointers) are *much* more expensive. They need difficult *branch target prediction*, which makes them significantly more expensive than even *conditional*  direct jumps/calls.

Comment: @EOF I can't find anything explaining what type of jumps exist, can you explain it?

Comment: Intel 64 and IA-32 manuals (http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf) and Agner's optimization guides (http://www.agner.org/optimize/) are your friends. The latter explains everything

Comment: Many DSPs have loop branch instructions which resolve early in the pipeline. PowerPC and Itanium have a loop count register and special loop branch instructions providing similar benefits. Even ordinary conditional branches can have low overhead if the condition can be set and evaluated sufficiently early. Accurate branch prediction reduces the frequency of pipeline flushes. Dynamic hammock predication can eliminate branches completely at the cost of data flow hazards. Other techniques are known.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A jump (or call) can be:

-either direct or indirect
-either relative or absolute
-either conditional or unconditional

**Conditional/unconditional** describes whether the branch is predicated or not.

**Relative/absolute** is a matter of encoding the *branch target*, either as an offset from the *current instruction pointer* or as the *absolute address* of the branch target.

If the branch is *absolute*, the target address can be stored as a variable, as it can be used from anywhere in the code (ideally). This means you can load this variable and perform an **indirect branch** to it.

These properties of a branch are almost orthogonal. Common combinations are:

-direct relative conditional. Your standard `if`.
-direct relative unconditional. Your standard `goto` and function call.
-direct absolute unconditional. Some function calls.
-direct absolute conditional. Rare, not many hardware architectures can encode such an instruction.
-indirect absolute unconditional. Function pointers. This is usually the most expensive branch type.

Other combinations tend to be difficult to encode.

There can be some further complications, for example `far branches`, but this should be a good start.